# Porting express generated folder vs fresh npm install?

Tags: node.js, express, package.json

I "express generated" a folder on ubuntu and synced everything into git. Now, I have the need to work on a mac. Can I simply pull the folder from git onto my mac, assume that all the important stuff (for instance my node_modules) will be ported and continue working on it there? Or would I have to do a fresh npm install using the package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are any native addons in the modules (compiled modules) you'll need to do a fresh install (at least on those) as they wont be binary-compatible.

Comment: Thank you for answering, although I am still a bit confused. As a beginner, I am not really sure which modules are compiled. Currently, I only have the default modules that are a result of `express --ejs pineapple-news` and additionally `npm install --save mongoose`. What would be a "best practise" (especially when working with others)... I mean should I be ignoring certain folders form git i.e. node_modules, and just have my team members do a fresh install? Or is it quite normal for team members to just work off of the same folder in git?

Comment: Best practice would be to ignore/exclude the `node_modules` folder from git, keep the package.json correct/up-to-date, and have team members/other machines do fresh installs.

Comment: Okay thank you so much. As a summary, I will keep all the folders like bin, models, public, routes, views and files like app.js and package.json within git. The only folder that I will be ignoring is node_modules. Is that correct? Or should I really be ignoring 'models' as well, which is a mongoose schema definitions folder?

Comment: `node_modules`, ide-specific files, and any temporary/cache should be ignored, everything else checked in. models should definitely be checked in.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much.